# Evaluate the definite integral $\int_{-1}^0(t^{\frac{1}{7}}-t^{\frac{2}{7}})dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

5.3

Evaluate the definite integral $\int_{-1}^0(t^{\frac{1}{7}}-t^{\frac{2}{7}})dt$

Can somebody verify this solution for me? Thanks!

---

$\int_{-1}^0(t^{\frac{1}{7}}-t^{\frac{2}{7}})dt$

$=\frac{t^{\frac{8}{7}}}{\frac{8}{7}}-\frac{t^{\frac{9}{7}}}{\frac{9}{7}}|_{-1}^0$

$\frac{7}{8}t^{\frac{8}{7}}-\frac{7}{9}t^{\frac{9}{7}}|_{-1}^0$

$=(\frac{7}{8}(0)^{\frac{8}{7}}-\frac{7}{9}(0)^{\frac{9}{7}})-(\frac{7}{8}(-1)^{\frac{8}{7}}-\frac{7}{9}(-1)^{\frac{9}{7}})$

Note that $(-1)^{\frac{8}{7}}=(-1)^{\frac{7}{7}}(-1)^{\frac{1}{7}}=-(-1)=1$

And $(-1)^{\frac{9}{7}}=(-1)^{\frac{2}{9}}(-1)^{\frac{7}{7}}=((-1)^2)^{\frac{1}{9}}(-1)^{\frac{7}{7}}=(1)^{\frac{1}{9}}(-1)=-1$

thus we have:

$=(\frac{7}{8}(0)^{\frac{8}{7}}-\frac{7}{9}(0)^{\frac{9}{7}})-(\frac{7}{8}(-1)^{\frac{8}{7}}-\frac{7}{9}(-1)^{\frac{9}{7}})$

$=0-(\frac{7}{8}(1)-\frac{7}{9}(-1))$

$0-(\frac{7}{8}+\frac{7}{9})$

$=-\frac{7}{8}-\frac{7}{9}$

$=-\frac{63}{72}-\frac{56}{72}$

$=\frac{-119}{72}$

Comment: $(-1)^\frac87=-(-1)^\frac17=-(-1)=1$, If you apply this to the calculation, it matches with the solution manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would be easier to you if you write $\sqrt[7]{t}=x$, then $t=x^7$ so $dt = 7x^6dx$ and now you have $$...=7\int_{-1}^0(x-x^2)x^6dx=...$$